# How to add custom field in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom, custom-field

I need 2 custom fields to add in the product description and those fields should be saved in the database and show on front end also. How can I add/edit the product form Magento admin panel?

So, generally, I need just guideline how to add the new custom field in Magento 2 for the entire product. Please guide me or show me some article if you have.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: For your comment attribute will do the same thing then why you want to show custom field

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write code for that, you just need to add attribute,

I think you are very new to magento so here is the tutorial how to add product attribute and how to use it

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-product-attribute-magento-2.html

for more detail just Google this term `create product attribute magento 2`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your answer is related to attribute. I do not want to add the attribute. I just want to add a new field that save in database, product detail, listing, shopping cart, add/edit product in admin. So, do you have any guideline?